# How to deal with JavaFX's threading model and large data changes

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have an `ObservableList` of "Tracks" displayed on a `TableView`. The `ObservableList`'s contents is based on metadata read from disk.

Sometimes I have to add or remove large chunks of data from the `ObservableList`. Some list modifications could take five seconds or longer (for example, by removing 5000 specific tracks from a list of 50000).

JavaFX dictates that any changes to the `ObservableList` backing the `TableView` only be done on the JavaFX thread. If I do a 5 second transaction on the JavaFX thread, the program UI will freeze for 5 seconds, an unacceptable behavior.

My current solution is to break my changes to the primary list into small transactions that do nothing other than modify the list. I put these changes into a queue and then process tasks from this queue each loop of the JavaFX thread for only a few hundred milliseconds, to avoid ever causing UI stutters.

This works well enough, but creates other problems I'm having trouble managing or encapsulating, and that makes me suspect it is not a very good solution.

For example, checking to see if a Track is in the `ObservableList` is now a complex process where I have to check the `ObservableList`, the pending action queue, and then figure out what the end-state of the list will be when all actions are processed, and return based on that. This is cumbersome and bug-prone. This model also creates problems with iterating over a list shared by multiple threads.

I'm looking for a better solution to this problem, because the list + pending change queue method is clunky and bug-prone.

The question distills down to: What is the best structure to manage changes to a large list of objects that must be displayed on a JavaFX `TableView`?

Comment: If this was Java Swing, I'd say use a [SwingWorker.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)  It manages the background task for you.  I don't know how to translate that into JFX (assuming any translation is needed).

Comment: @markspace The equivalent to a SwingWorker is a [Task](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or [Service](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) (which both happen to inherit the Worker interface).

Comment: Are you just changing which elements are in the list?  Or are you possibly modifying the elements themselves?

Comment: Both changes to what elements are in the list and modifications to the elements in the list.

Comment: If there's a good solution that requires that the items be immutable, I could probably work with that by rendering changes as a remove then add, rather than as an edit. It would be best if items could be edited.

Comment: Both JavaFX's `Task` / `Service` (as @VGR stated) and [RxJavaFX](https://thomasnield.gitbooks.io/rxjavafx-guide/content/4.%20Collections.html) can help move the list management work off the main JavaFX GUI thread.

Comment: Indeed a new list can be prepared in another thread, and then in the event thread thre current list can be updated.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yea, I was working on this last night and came across that idea.  It works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that seems to be working well is something like this:

1. Create an ObservableList called `items` that is the canonical data set.
2. The worker thread can modify `items` at will.
3. Add a change listener to `items`.  As changes are pushed to items, make a note of what the change is and put it in a Queue called `pendingChanges`.
4. Create a second ObservableList called `displayCache` that is the data set displayed in JavaFX.
5. At regular and small intervals, have the JavaFX thread pull Changes from `pendingChanges`and apply them to the `displayCache`.

In this way, we have a dataset that is real-time accurate, and the items displayed in the JavaFX UI are trying to catch up to that dataset. If the UI falls behind for a few seconds, that doesn't matter at all.

I implemented this last night, along with some code to manage blocking and locking appropriately, and it worked great basically right away.  I am able to encapsulate all of this into a single class, which means the rest of my code doesn't have to think about managing the cache, managing threading issues, or anything like that.

This is the inverse of the previous solution.  I had been making `displayCache` the canonical dataset, which created a slew of other problems. By having a separate, off-JavaFXThread dataset that can be updated in real time, I am able to sidestep all of those problems and put the delay where it belongs -- between the data set and the UI.